# How to retrieve multiple Ids from a map

Tags: apex, map

I have a `List<String>` which will return some records as below.

```
List<String> ids = ['abcdef','xyzabc','lmnopq']; 
List<Object2> obj2List = [SELECT id, field1__c, field2__c where field2__c IN : ids];
```

This above list will return multiple records with same field2__c value.

**Object2 records sample data:**

**Id     field1__c     field2__c**

Id1       890078         abcdef

Id2       567876         lmnopq

Id3       234456         lmnopq

Id4       752111         abcdef

Id5       789908         abcdef

Id6       324543         uvwxyz

Id7       665577         uvwxyz

Id8       999000         uvwxyz

Id9       562112         lmnopq

Now, from this list I need to get the records of same field2__c values and send it to another method. For this, I created a Map and added the list of records to Map as below

```
Map<Id, Object2> newmap = new Map<Id, Object2>();
for(Object2 obj: obj2List){
   newmap.put(obj.field2__c, obj);
}
```

My map is now loaded with all 9 records. Now I need to get the records with same field2__c values to a list and send it to another method. I'm trying something like below but it is not working

```
for(String id: ids){
   `List<Object2> ob2Values = newmap.get(id);` //I'm getting error at this line saying illegal assignment from Object2 to List<Object2>

    callNewMethod(ob2Values);
}
```

I can directly loop over the Ids and query the records in loop and call my method directly but trying to follow best practices, I'm refraining from writing queries in loops.

Any way to alter my code in 2nd for loop so that I can get the list of same field2__c values and pass them to my method each time.

Answer (score 1):

In a map, the put method will evict a value that has the same key. In other words, your map will only have 3 values in it:

- Id5 789908 abcdef
- Id9 562112 lmnopq
- Id8 999000 uvwxyz

Instead, you need to use a `Map<Id, List<Object2>>` or similar.

Your mapping process should look like this:

```
Map<Id, List<Object2>> newmap = new Map<Id, List<Object2>>();
for(Object2 obj: obj2List){
  List<Object> objectValues = newmap.get(obj.field2__c);
  if(objectValues == null) {
    newmmap.put(obj.field2__c, objectValues = new List<Object2>());
  }
  objectValues.add(obj);
}
```

You'll need to change the rest of the code as appropriate.